# Creating multiple userform objects using one Class Module

Tags: vba, excel, oop

I have a userform (shown below) [image: My userform]

When I press the button "Add Another Position", I want to add another row of that listbox and 3 textboxes. While this would be simple enough, I also need those dynamically created form controls to have their own events in which they will affect each other (e.g. you enter text in the textbox and the listbox selects a corresponding item).

I was planning on using a class module to create these additional rows, but I do not know enough vba yet.

It is indeterminate how many rows/positions will be added, so I can't add these in during design time.

Here is the (probably very sloppy) code that I have tried so far:

```
     Public WithEvents PositionLB As ListBox
     Public WithEvents SurveyCode As TextBox
     Public WithEvents FunctionCode As TextBox
     Public WithEvents PositionCode As TextBox

     Private Sub PositionLB_Change()
         'Irrelevant to question
     End Sub

     Private Sub PositionCode_Change()
         'Irrelevant to question
     End Sub
```

Comment: Quite a few similar Q's to be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvba%5D+dynamic+userform  If this is your first time implementing something like this I'd start with just adding one control per line and get that working first.

Comment: The listbox being in each class, you will end with one (bigger) listbox having multiple times the same code. Advice: code the listbox normaly (ie. in the userform code). Also i don't know what the 3 textboxes mean to do, but couldn't you just use those on your example as global textbox's for search (as there is only on search button, i don't see the point having multiple textboxes). An other solution is instead 3 textbox, having only 3 combobox with all the last entered code searchs.